# python sort file path based on created time

Tags: python

I have python array with filepath in it, I need to sort the files path based on created date. Is there any inbuilt functionality exist for it.

```
  files = ["/path1/filename.text", "/path2/filename.text", "/path2/filename.text"]
```

Comment: Here is another possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/539024/4985099

Comment: The above link demonstrates how to get the creation date for a file. You can use this as the `key` argument in `sorted` for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213033/sort-a-list-of-lists-with-a-custom-compare-function

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.